# Is it possible to make double click dynamic ads from HTML5 canvas / flash export

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, dynamic

I would like to create dynamic html5 doubleclick banners using HTML5 Canvas export (as im familiar with flash but can't code html5). I would create the main animation, but then plan to partner with a JS/HTML5 developer who would assign the variables and make the elements dynamic within the HTML5 Canvas doc afterward.

Please could you advise if this method would work / if it's possible? I'm new to html5 so any thoughts would be great.

Many thanks!!

Comment: Of course this method would work and is possible, but this is far too broad to be able to answer. There are an infinite number of ways to do what you are asking for, but in short, it's definitely possible.

Comment: fantastic thank you!